# Microsoft Headless PowerApp

Tags: azure-functions, powerapps, headless

Within Microsoft PowerApps, I have two different connectors.  The first connector is an HTTPS GET from a secure endpoint.  The second is a Sage 100cloud web api endpoint.  Is it possible to create a headless PowerApp whereby on an invocation, I can pull from the GET endpoint and essentially POST to the second endpoint?

Comment: Hm. Unless you created a [Custom Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-powerapps), I don't believe there isn't an "HTTPS GET" connector in [Power Apps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/). Either way, you can create a "headless" automaton by using [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/). You can even connect to your Custom Connector.

Comment: Thank you, Power Automate was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- PowerApps, app on start screen, call a power automate which will perfrom your GET.
- Once you have the response back in your powerapps, Then perform Post via Powerautomate.
- All these steps could be performed Apponstart.